# relative pronouns: “where I'd never been before” or “to which I'd never been before”?

Tags: questions, relative-pronouns

I did an exercise, and there was a sentence that make me confused. Can you help me with it.

> Yesterday we visited the City Museum, (______) I'd never been before.

There are 4 answers to chose: *which*, *where*, *to that*, *to which*.

I chose "where" but the correct answer is *"**to which**"*. I can't understand it.

Comment: See the [ell.se] site.

Comment: "Where" is fine; here it simply means "to x", where "x" = "the city museum". The alternant "to which" is fine too, though somewhat formal.

Comment: @marcellothearcane the question seems trickier than at first sight. I think it's fine for EL&U, it's not such a basic English language question.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with others that either "where" or "to which" could work in that sentence. [Shoe](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/509962/225122) mentions pied-piping for "to which". I think "[where](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/where)" works because it can be substituted with "in which". Which to use is based on preference. I'd expect more people would choose "where" because "to which" feels overly formal.

However, you have another dilemma: Given two correct answers, how do you choose which one to select?

- If you are taking a class, does either answer fit into recently covered topics?
- If you know the person who wrote the question, does that person have a particularly formal usage style?
- Sometimes there are additional instructions that specifically exclude some correct answers. Double check to ensure you haven't overlooked them.
- Analyze the answer choices. The correct answer is often written first with distracters written later. This means there is a high probability that one or more of the distracters will resemble the correct answer.

  - "which" – by dropping "to" from "to which"
  - "to that" – by substituting "which" with "that" in "to which"
  - "where" – this is the odd one out

  Notice that the words "to" and "which" appear in twice as many of the answers as any of the other words. This means there is a very good chance that those words will appear in the (intended) "correct" answer. In this case, just string them together – "to which".

  Suppose "to where" were also an option. The word "to" would have appeared thrice, while "where" and "which" would both have appeared twice. This analysis still favors "to which", but it's not as strong as before. I also now wonder if the intended distracter was "to where" instead of "where".

This type of answer is unfair and would have been revised prior to administration in a standardized exam. If it somehow made it past the review process, it would be dropped during scoring. For educational purposes, it's useful to analyze why answers are correct or not, as you are doing.

Comment: You make some good suggestions on how to determine the better of two equally grammatical answers. And certainly if the question is part of an exercise to practise pied-piping then _to which_ is the only possibility.  But I think it is unfair for the teacher to include more than one possible answer to decontextualised multiple-choice questions and expect the learner to second-guess the 'correct' answer.

Comment: @Shoe I agree it's unfair. On standardized exams, this type of question would have been revised prior to administration or dropped during scoring.

Answer (score 0):

The suggested correct answer *to which* is based on the construction *been to* (i.e. *visited*).

For example:

> I had never **been to** (*visited*) the City Museum before.

If the construction is used in a relative clause, the preposition must be retained. In everyday English the preposition typically goes to the end of the clause:

> The City Museum is a museum *which* I had never been *to*.

In more formal English the preposition is [pied-piped](https://www.thoughtco.com/pied-piping-syntax-1691627) in front of the relative pronoun *which*. This produces the 'correct' answer:

> The City Museum is a museum *to which* I had never *been*.

That said, your answer *where* also works here:

> The City Museum is a museum *where* I had never *been* before.

This alternative can be interpreted as *been in* rather than *been to*. This is a marginal difference but it does justify the acceptability of your answer.

Comment: Can you explain how "been in" works to justify the use of "where"?

Comment: @xiota. For example, _The City Museum is a place where I have spent many happy hours_. Here _where_ refers to the location _in which_ I have been. This contrasts with __been to__, which broadly means _visited_.